# download data as .xls format file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to download list data as .xls file.My controller code is follows.

```
     [HttpGet]
        public void AttendeeListToExport()
        {
            string campaign_id = string.Empty;
            campaign_id = ((MemberProfile)HttpContext.Current.Profile).HOWCampaignID;
            AutoCRM.Services.HOW.Attendee.Manage manage = new AutoCRM.Services.HOW.Attendee.Manage();
            DataSet lst = manage.AttendeeListToExport(campaign_id);
            if (lst != null)
            {
                if (lst.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dt = lst.Tables[0];
                    // Export all the details to Excel
                    string filename = campaign_id + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".xls";
                    Export objExport = new Export();
                    objExport.ExportDetails(dt, Export.ExportFormat.Excel, filename);
                }
            }
        }
```

js code

```
$('#exportToExcel').on("click", function () {
        alert('hi');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Attendee/AttendeeListToExport",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

code executing correctly but file not downloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Controller action returned a FileResult, you could download this from your javascript function like this:

```
$('#exportToExcel').on("click", function () {
    window.open("/api/Attendee/AttendeeListToExport", "_blank");
});
```

Comment: window.open("/api/Attendee/AttendeeListToExport"); this is getting

Comment: Sorry that was due to a typo in my code(forgot "), it is fixed now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can download file through javascript in following both ways :

**Using HiddenIFrame :**

```
var downloadURL = function downloadURL(url) {
    var iframe;
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader';
    iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
    if (iframe === null) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
        iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;   
}
```

**Using Jquery :**

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'uploads/file.doc';
});

<a href="no-script.html">Download now!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't download files using ajax.  You have to use a hidden iframe or link directly to the file.